# Strip out EXIF data from Image using Cropit

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, exif

I am using Cropit (http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) to zoom and crop user uploaded images - but on some devices when image is selected in comes in rotated. Zoom and crop occurs prior to image upload (loads images locally via FileReader) so I was hoping to perform 'whatever needs to be done' in the CropIt js file.

I've done some research and it looks like the best way to correct this is to remove the orientation exif data from the image (versus rotating using canvas as the orientation data would remain and could cause undesired effects when displaying image later). I can't seem to figure out where to add code (and what code to add!) in the jquery.cropit.js.

Thanks!

Comment: saving a canvas would not keep any image exif or orientation info in the output...

Comment: perhaps, but when you select an image (with cropit) and it brings it in to the div to crop and zoom the image is rotated which makes for awkward editing.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy solution to that at the moment. [This issue](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/issues/75) describes the same problem -- feel free to follow it so you'll be notified when it's addressed. In the mean time [the library](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) mentioned in it may be helpful.